# Angular 6 dynamic change data

Tags: angular, web-component

Please help me to understand, In the application client side, I have a  component that show a user data table information. If the data in the server side has been changed, the updates must be shown in the client side (add some elements to the table or to remove). 
How can I do this dynamically?

Comment: Welcome and gratz on your 1st question here :) First of all, try sharing your code samples with your question, it is a better way to get accurate answers, and easier for other people to create solutions. For your question, you should check out the documentation for Services and HTTP from [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) After that if you stuck, please share your effort for us to help further.

Comment: Please try to share a minimal, verifiable example of what you have tried so far. This will help others understand and answer it in a better way.

Comment: Use ngDoCheck with time interval API call and I think you can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to subscribe to a function that retrieves data from your server, and update your client side data if any changes occur.

A function like this would query your server-side endpoint:

```
GetServerData() {
    return this.http.get('your_endpoint_url').pipe(
        map(response => {
            return response;
        })
    );
}
```

You would then subscribe to this function:

```
this.GetServerData().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)
    // Fires if new data is received from the server. Use response to update your client side data table
});
```

If you wanted to constantly test for server side changes you could use an interval timer (probably in your component constructor or other lifecycle hook) to trigger GetServerData() periodically, as suggested by [M.Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8947430/m-ismail) e.g:

```
setInterval(this.GetServerData, 5000);
```

This will fetch data from the server every five seconds, but be aware that every interval trigger subscription function, whether the server side data has changed or not.

Depending on the volume of data you might check whether there has been a change and then update the UI if it has, or just update the UI with the latest batch of data, regardless of whether it has changed.

To be honest if you need a very close link async connection between client side and server side there may be better solutions, which again [M.Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8947430/m-ismail) has suggested in his answer. But this is one method if you just want to use Angular.

Comment: This should have been a comment on the question.

Comment: But will it refresh component data some each period of time?

Comment: Have updated my answer - as M.Ismail suggests you can use an interval timer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have two solutions, the first one is to create a web service that fetch the data each period of time for example 10 seconds.
The second way, the more sufficient way, you can use web socket between the two application side.